# Trying to understand how C++ pairs can be converted to C code

Tags: c++, c, converters

So I'm trying to do a little test project and I was watching a tutorial on how I could make part of the code, the problem is, on the video the user uses C++ and I'm working on C.
I tried figuring it out and searching a bit, but it's still quite confusing to me.

So the piece of code I can't understand is this:

```
pair<int, int> generateUnPos() {

    int occupied = 1;
    int line, column;

    while(occupied){
        line = rand() % 4;
        column = rand() %4;
        if(board[line][column] == 0){
            occupied = 0;
        }
    }

    return make_pair(line, column);
}
```

I know it as something to do with structs but I can't figure it out. Can somebody help me out.

Comment: If you're working with `C`, then you should be learning from `C` material, not `C++` material.  C++ and C are two different languages.

Comment: To learn C programming, read [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat pair as a struct in C.

```
typedef struct {
    int line;
    int column;
} Position;
```

Then this piece of code should be:

```
Position generateUnPos() {

    int occupied = 1;
    int line, column;

    while (occupied) {
        line = rand() % 4;
        column = rand() % 4;
        if (board[line][column] == 0) {
            occupied = 0;
        }
    }
    Position pos = {line, column};
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `return { line, column };` is valid C. You need to use a compound literal like I did.

Comment: Good idea calling the structure `Position`. Makes it a bit more readable than re-using pair.

Comment: This is what I'd do in C++, too!

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica, Yes you are right. But I get the following warnings: warning: excess elements in struct initializer

Comment: Oh I see how it can be done, but is it necessary to initialize the line and column variable again inside Position? I thought they were already initialized. And sorry if it's a dumb question im kinda new to C

Comment: @Ugabuga, I assume you are talking about this "Position pos = {line, column}". This line is initializing an instance of the structure Position, not the line/column itself.

Answer (score 5):

Templates don't exist in C, so you need to make a custom type, like this:

```
struct pair_int_int {
    int first;
    int second;
};
```

Then return it like this:

```
return (struct pair_int_int){line, column};
```

Comment: An alternative would be to pass in pointers and return nothing: `void generateUnPos(int * line, int * column)`

Comment: @user4581301: your alternative could be slower, and is less readable. On [some implementations](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf), two processor registers might be used to return such a pair.